# Error while trying to play webm with MSE,chunks not appending , video stopping

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash, media-source

I want to play webm whose duration is >5s (1.32 mins)
[this webm](https://ia800502.us.archive.org/10/items/WebmVp8Vorbis/webmvp8.webm).

I'have been trying to modify this example, when I run it, chunks are not appending and video stops at some point, and I'm getting this error:

InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));

Could someone clarify please?

```
<script>
    var FILE = 'test2.webm'; //that webm
    var NUM_CHUNKS = 10;
    var video = document.querySelector('video');

    window.MediaSource = window.MediaSource || window.WebKitMediaSource;
    if (!!!window.MediaSource) {
        alert('MediaSource API is not available');
    }

    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();

    //document.querySelector('[data-num-chunks]').textContent = NUM_CHUNKS;

    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

    function callback(e) {
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"');

        logger.log('mediaSource readyState: ' + this.readyState);

        GET(FILE, function(uInt8Array) {
            var file = new Blob([uInt8Array], {
                type: 'video/webm'
            });
            var chunkSize = Math.ceil(file.size / NUM_CHUNKS);

            logger.log('num chunks:' + NUM_CHUNKS);
            logger.log('chunkSize:' + chunkSize + ', totalSize:' + file.size);

            // Slice the video into NUM_CHUNKS and append each to the media element.
            var i = 0;
            (function readChunk_(i) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                // Reads aren't guaranteed to finish in the same order they're started in,
                // so we need to read + append the next chunk after the previous reader
                // is done (onload is fired).
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(e.target.result));
                    logger.log('appending chunk:' + i);
                    if (i == NUM_CHUNKS - 1) {
                        mediaSource.endOfStream();
                    } else {
                        if (video.paused) {
                            video.play(); // Start playing after 1st chunk is appended.
                        }
                        readChunk_(++i);
                    }
                };

                var startByte = chunkSize * i;
                var chunk = file.slice(startByte, startByte + chunkSize);

                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(chunk);
            })(i); // Start the recursive call by self calling.
        });
    }

    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', callback, false);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceopen', callback, false);

    mediaSource.addEventListener('webkitsourceended', function(e) {
        logger.log('mediaSource readyState: ' + this.readyState);
    }, false);

    function GET(url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.send();

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                alert("Unexpected status code " + xhr.status + " for " + url);
                return false;
            }
            callback(new Uint8Array(xhr.response));
        };
    }
</script>
<script>
    function Logger(id) {
        this.el = document.getElementById('log');
    }
    Logger.prototype.log = function(msg) {
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
        fragment.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        this.el.appendChild(fragment);
    };

    Logger.prototype.clear = function() {
        this.el.textContent = '';
    };

    var logger = new Logger('log');
</script>
<script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-22014378-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script');
        ga.type = 'text/javascript';
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your video is working well in my player based on example you provided. I do not call mediaSource.endOfStream(); and i am not slicing file using FileReader class (useless).

**Use Range http header to get slices from you webserver directly.**

Example:

```
function GET(url, from = 0, to = '') {
    return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", `bytes=${from}-${to}`);
        xhr.send();

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (xhr.status != 200 && xhr.status != 206) {
                alert("Unexpected status code " + xhr.status + " for " + url);
                reject(e);
            }
            accept(xhr.response);
        };
    });
}
```